# how to partition a sql query result table in particular set of rows in SSRS

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

consider a scenario.. for my query

```
select A.Name, B.Time, C.Class
from A  left join B on B.b = A.b
left join C on C.c = B.c
```

derives the following result..

```
*****************************************************
Name            Time   Class
------------------------------------------------------
Amit Kumar      360    IT
Amit Kumar      180    Comps
Sanjay Sharma   360    IT
Sanjay Sharma   150    Comps
    .            .      .
    .            .      .

*********************************************************
```

Now I want to represent this in ssrs in VS 2012 as

```
************************************************************
Name            Time   Class
------------------------------------------------------
Amit Kumar      360    IT
Amit Kumar      180    Comps

Total Time = 540


Sanjay Sharma   360    IT
Sanjay Sharma   150    Comps

Total Time = 510

**********************************************************
```

how can I accomplished it using Mysql or SSRS(Visual studio 2012) for every particular user ,I was had used Join in queries and also tried Group by rollup, group by .. with cube ,  but with later two I don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I would not edit the query.

In the SSRS Table, I would add a Row Group for Name, with a Footer row for the totals.